# Как принять JSON в POST запросе на PHP?

Tags: php, json, api

Как принять JSON в POST запросе, когда я нажимаю на кнопку, то отправляю запрос, и если мне в ответ не возвращает 'OK', надо вывести ошибку

файл payviaPOS.php где делается запрос

```
 $url = "PayViaPOS/";
    $api->post = array(
    'ProductOrderId' => $_POST['ProductOrderId'],
    'price'=> $_POST['price']
    );  
    $data = $api->sendrequest($url);
    //print_r($data);
    }
    if($data['PayViaPOS']) {
    $result = [ 
    'price' => $data['price'],
    'ProductOrderId' => $ProductOrderId
    ];
    } else {
    $result = [
    'Error' => 1
    ];
    }
        die(json_encode($result));
```

ajax запрос:

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#PayViaPOS", function() {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: '/engine/ajax/PayViaPOS.php',  
data: 
{
action:"PayViaPOS",
ProductOrderId: <?=$_GET['productOrderId']?>,
hash: "<?php echo md5($config['salt'].$_GET['productOrderId']); ?>",
price: '<?=$order->getCalcSum()?>'
},

});
});

</script>
```

в Ajax запросе, я с помощью `GET` хочу получить данные из `API`, и если все `OK`, в модальном окне должно вывести `ОК`, если нет, то ошибку

Answer (score 2):

> Как принять JSON в POST запросе

Разобрать входной поток (php://input)

[Потоки ввода-вывода](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php), прочитать можно одной из команд: [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php), [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php)

p.s. пройдитесь по [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/) к php, сэкономит кучу времени это вам